# Match index function from excel in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

There is a match index function in Excel that i use to match if the elements are present in the required column

```
=iferror(INDEX($B$2:$F$8,MATCH($J4,$B$2:$B$8,0),MATCH(K$3,$B$1:$F$1,0)),0)
```

This is the function i am using right now and it is yielding me good results but I want to implement it in python.

```
brand   N   Z   None
Honor   63  96  190     
Tecno   0   695 763
```

from this table I want

```
  brand L   N   Z
  Honor 0   63  96
  Tecno 0   0   695
```

It should compare both the column and index and give the appropriate value

i have tried the lookup function in python but that gives me the

```
ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels
```

Comment: That's simple in pandas, but to show how, I would need some more info. Which columns do you want to match both tables on? and which are the columns you want to compare? e.g do you just want the columns N, Z of table 1 be matched with the same columns in table 2 for the row with the same brand? and what do you expect, if the brand apprears two times in table 2. In that case excel would just take the first match. If you want the same in pandas, it is a bit more difficult. If you don't need it becomes easier.

Comment: One suggestion: could you add, what you do by the excel code? please note, that the names of the excel functions are not known by all people and unfortunately in non-english excel versions the function names are (at least sometines) translated to the language the excel version was built for. From looking it up, I guess you are taking a value from a two-dimensional table based on a "index-row" / "index-column" along the table border that you match with some value. Maybe a pircture Ior if pssible a part of the table in text form, would help for the understanding.

Comment: The main problem here is the data which is generated may or may not contain the all the headers in the standard table i want to compare both columns and rows headers and give appropriate value else it should just print Nan or zero which is i can change later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you basically do with your excel formula, is creating something like a pivot table, you can also do that with pandas. E.g. like this:

```
# Define the columns and brands, you like to have in your result table
# along with the dataframe in variable df it's the only input
columns_query=['L', 'N', 'Z']
brands_query=['Honor', 'Tecno', 'Bar']

# no begin processing by selecting the columns
# which should be shown and are actually present
# add the brand, even if it was not selected
columns_present= {col for col in set(columns_query) if col in df.columns}
columns_present.add('brand')
# select the brands in question and take the
# info in columns we identified for these brands
# from this generate a "flat" list-like data
# structure using melt
# it contains records containing
# (brand, column-name and cell-value)
flat= df.loc[df['brand'].isin(brands_query), columns_present].melt(id_vars='brand')

# if you also want to see the columns and brands,
# for which you have no data in your original df
# you can use the following lines (if you don't
# need them, just skip the following lines until
# the next comment)
# the code just generates data points for the
# columns and rows, which would otherwise not be
# displayed and fills them wit NaN (the pandas 
# equivalent for None)
columns_missing= set(columns_query).difference(columns_present)
brands_missing=  set(brands_query).difference(df['brand'].unique())
num_dummies= max(len(brands_missing), len(columns_missing))
dummy_records= {
    'brand': list(brands_missing) +     [brands_query[0]]  * (num_dummies - len(brands_missing)),
    'variable': list(columns_missing) + [columns_query[0]] * (num_dummies - len(columns_missing)),
    'value': [np.NaN] * num_dummies
}
dummy_records= pd.DataFrame(dummy_records)
flat= pd.concat([flat, dummy_records], axis='index', ignore_index=True)

# we get the result by the following line:
flat.set_index(['brand', 'variable']).unstack(level=-1)
```

For my testdata, this outputs:

```
         value             
variable     L     N      Z
brand                      
Bar        NaN   NaN    NaN
Honor      NaN  63.0   96.0
Tecno      NaN   0.0  695.0
```

The testdata is (note, that above we don't see col None and row Foo, but we see row Bar and column L, which are actually not present in the testdata, but were "queried"):

```
   brand   N    Z  None
0  Honor  63   96   190
1  Tecno   0  695   763
2    Foo   8  111   231
```

You can generate this testdata using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

raw=\
"""brand   N   Z   None
Honor   63  96  190     
Tecno   0   695 763
Foo     8   111 231"""

df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw), sep='\s+')
```

**Note:** the result as shown in the output is a regular pandas dataframe. So in case you plan to write the data back to a excel sheet, there should be no problem (pandas provides methods to read/write dataframes to/from excel-files).

Comment: This might work the only problem is why you adding extra name variable can't we do this with out that i am trying to understand that  thanks anyway i will take this from here if i made any changes i will post here..

Comment: Which variable do you mean? Actually a python variable or a column? If you mean python variables, of course you can also combine several steps without storing the intermediate result. I often store the intermediate result because I think the code is easier to read and to debug. It is also easier to describe what the code does, as I try to do in my comments.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use Pandas for this action. You can do it with simple python as well. Read from one text file and print out matched and processed fields.

Basic file reading in Python goes like this. Where datafile.csv is your file. This reads all the lines in one file and prints out right result. First you need to save your file in .csv format so there is a separator between fields ','.

```
import csv # use csv
print('brand L N Z') # print new header
with open('datafile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    next(spamreader, None) # skip old header
    for row in spamreader:
        # You need to add Excel Match etc... logic here.
        print(row[0], 0, row[1], row[2]) # print output
```

Input file:

```
brand,N,Z,None
Honor,63,96,190
Tecno,0,695,763
```

Prints out:

```
brand L N Z
Honor 0 63 96
Tecno 0 0 695
```

(I am not familiar with Excel Match-function so you may need to add some logic to above Python script to get logic working with all your data.)

Comment: Hi, maybe you are right, and pandas is not required, but I think the question is not about how to open a file, so if you have a solution about how to get the cell, it would be helpfull, if you could add it. Btw. if you do this by hand, wouldn't it be much easier to use pythons csv module?

Comment: I am not sure how Match works in Excel and that logic must be added to script. I think Python CSV module could also be used.

Comment: It would ease up things to use csv. Otherwise you have to care about splitting fields and removing of quoting yourself and that is not as easy as it seems at first!

Comment: Now it is using csv.

Comment: You're right, it could be done like this. You would just have to drop all columns from the original file, that are not in the list of requested columns and all rows, which do not belong to the required brands. That's really a light-weight solution. Only if you want to read write from excel and maybe plan to do other stuff as well, it will get to it's limits I guess.

Comment: what if  my data contain the only L & N then again i have to change the column position based on your answer.      That is not so reliable i am automating this because i don't want to do any manual thing.